# View filter [me] not working correctly after upgrade from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, upgrade, filter

We upgraded SP 2010 foundation to SP 2013 Enterprise. But I noticed that list view filter `[me]` is not filtering for items that were created in SP 2010 (before the upgrade).

For example a view "Created by me" has a filter like:

```
Created by = [me]
```

But if I filter by whole name `John Smith` then it works. Also it works for all items that were created already in SP 2013.

I know that it is related to the prefix to usernames that we have now, like `(i:0#.w|domainname\JSmith)`. On SP 2010 we had just `domainname\JSmith`.

Any chances to fix this `[me]` that it would show all items regardless if the username has the prefix `i:0#.w|` or not?

Comment: this could also be a language problem, in which language are yoyu running SharePoint? - calculated columns for example use translated formulas also

Comment: There also seems to be a known error like this. Which Cumulative Update have you installed? - Might be fixed by May 2015 CU

Comment: I have 15.0.4569.1506 version, so seems May 2015 CU is installed?